# How to scale host server resources to run multiple applications at once?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualhost, scaling, sizing

I have to set up a relatively big system consisting of Virtual Machines, where I will need to run several different applications. The applications will be provided to me as black boxes, either in form of software to be installed by myself (on a new VM), or in the form of Virtual Machine containing already everything for an application.

My task is to set up a host server and estimate its general resources, which will be then distributed between all Virtual Machines in my system. Some of the applications are more demanding than the others, and I have also time deadlines, so it could happen that all the application need to be executed simultaneously.

For each application I have the resources description it needs (but no corresponding time and performance estimates), so that I know how many processors and processors cores I normally will need for a single app. But how should I do with all of them running simultaneously? Should I simply add together the requirements or is there some common formula for scaling of the host servers general CPUs, Memory and Storage resources?

And one more questions. Such a system with distribution of real physical resources between several VMs - is it already a cluster? Or not yet?

Comment: This isn't on topic here, as it isn't a programming question. This might be on topic elsewhere on SE -  ServerFault, perhaps, but check their FAQ before posting there.

Comment: There probably isn't a common formula, no - it is (a) what resources do your apps require to be functional, and (b) what resources do your apps require to work optimally? Ideally each piece of software will come with technical documentation specifying what resources it needs to run well.

Comment: Assuming this isn't just an academic question, are you happy that the elements in your system are actually scalable? For example, has heavy work been moved to job queues, has it been tested under a realistic number of users, etc?